# How to explain these p.values from model and from Anova type 2 and type 3?

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I am trying to test the effect of each single predictor as well as their combination in predicting an outcome, and I am confusing how to explain these p values:

```
set.seed(123)
Y<-rnorm(100,10,3)
X1<-rbinom(100,1,0.5)
X2<-Y+runif(100,1,50)
X3<-rbinom(100,50,0.3)
fit<-glm(Y~X1+X2+X3)
#p.value(1)
round(summary(fit)$coef,4)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   8.9131     1.3292  6.7056   0.0000
X1            0.2781     0.5336  0.5211   0.6035
X2            0.0541     0.0182  2.9662   0.0038
X3           -0.0462     0.0829 -0.5577   0.5784
#p.value(2)
Anova(fit,type=2)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: Y
   LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
X1   0.2716  1   0.602278   
X2   8.7983  1   0.003015 **
X3   0.3110  1   0.577077 
#p.value(3)
Anova(fit,type=3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: Y
   LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
X1   0.2716  1   0.602278   
X2   8.7983  1   0.003015 **
X3   0.3110  1   0.577077  
#p.value(4)
single.p.value<-NULL
for (var in c("X1","X2","X3")){
    single.p.value[var]<-summary(glm(as.formula(paste("Y", var, sep="~"))))$coef[2,4]
}
single.p.value
         X1          X2          X3 
0.433781616 0.003440499 0.995918785
```

When are the `p.values` different between `car::Anova` type-II and type-III? Any body can give a clear explanation of these 4 sets of pvalues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between Type II and Type III p-values can be seen in the presence of interaction terms ([here is a good overview with examples for R](http://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/)).  To see this, consider:

```
fit_interaction <- glm(Y ~ X1 * X2)
Anova(fit_interaction, type = 2)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: Y
      LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
X1      0.2862  1   0.592644   
X2      8.4761  1   0.003598 **
X1:X2   0.1831  1   0.668693   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Anova(fit_interaction, type = 3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: Y
      LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
X1      0.3618  1    0.54751  
X2      5.7252  1    0.01672 *
X1:X2   0.1831  1    0.66869  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The `Anova` function in the **car** package uses [Wald Chi-square test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test) to generate the p-values it displays.  These can either be Type II or Type III p-values.  Type II p-values are calculated using the sums of squares for each main effect conditional on the other main effects.  Type III p-values conditions the sums of squares on the interaction term as well.

The regular `anova` and `aov` functions in R compute Type I effects (see link above for details) which is rarely what you are interested and will change depending on the ordering of the terms in the function.

The `summary()` function calculates the p-value based on the *t*-statistic of the effect (effect divided by standard error).

The last set of p-values are also based on the *t*-statistic of the effect but they are unadjusted for the other term in the model.  In other words the effect of each term is different from the one found in the model `fit`.